# Computing the current angle of a rotating image Iphone Versus Android

Tags: android, iphone, rotation

To find the current angle of the image wheeler in iOS.

```
- (float) currentAngle
   {

float angle = radiansToDegrees(atan2(wheeler.transform.b, wheeler.transform.a)) + 1;    
if(angle < 0) {
    angle = 360 + angle;
}
return angle;
    }
```

Does Android have the equivalent tranform object that has the property of transform.a and transform.b ?  Right now I am this code to perform the rotation of a image object in its own axis.  but I need find out its current position or angle periodically.

```
   RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360,  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,    0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
             0.5f);

     anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
     anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
     anim.setDuration(1900);
     imageView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Using your -(float) currentAngle function I have solved very critical problem in my application. Thank you so much.